# RHEL8 Parted command mkpart error invalid number

Tags: swap, rhel8, parted

Trying to create a swap partion using the following query

parted -s /dev/nvme0n2 mkpart extended linux-swap 1000MB 2000MB

[root@rhel8vmware ~]# parted -s /dev/nvme0n2 print free
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n2: 5369MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1024B   1049kB  1048kB           Free Space
1      1049kB  1000MB  999MB   primary
1000MB  5369MB  4368MB           Free Space

[root@rhel8vmware ~]# parted -s /dev/nvme0n2 mkpart extended linux-swap 1000MB 2000MB
Error: Invalid number.

[image: Free space size and error]